# ActiveAdmin Form Multiple Nested HMT relationships with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many

i'm new to ActiveAdmin and Rails and i struggle on something to build up my ActiveAdmin interface.

Consider the following models :

```
class PageType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fields, class_name: 'PageField'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fields, allow_destroy: true
end


class PageField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page_type
  has_many :page_has_fields
  has_many :pages, through: :page_has_fields

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :page_has_fields, allow_destroy: true
end

class PageHasField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :page_field
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page_type
  has_many :page_has_fields, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :page_fields, through: :page_has_fields

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :page_fields, allow_destroy: true
end
```

In Active Admin I want to create some page templates to handle "static" pages. And in each of the pages, I want to update the content of each fields related to the templates page.

Thus far, what I did worked with this code :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Page do

  permit_params :name, :page_type_id, :page_id,
                :page_fields_attributes => [:id, :name, :field_type, :page_id,
                  :page_has_fields_attributes => [:id, :content, :page_id]
                ]

  form do |f|
    f.inputs

    f.has_many :page_fields, heading: false, new_record: false do |g|
      g.inputs :name, :required

      g.has_many :page_has_fields, new_record: false do |h|
        h.input :content if h.object.page_id == f.object.id
      end
    end

    f.actions
  end

end
```

But the second has_many seems really wrong to me, and i'm sure there are a better solution to this problem. 
If i don't go with the "if", inputs are created for the right fields, but for every single page.

Is there a way to specify an ID or a parameter in has_many ? Or a better tag to handle situation like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your setup to something more like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register Page do
  ...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :some_column
      f.input :some_other_column
      f.input :page_fields, as: :check_boxes, checked: PageField.all.map(&:name)
      f.input :page_has_fields, as: :check_boxes, checked: PageField.all.map(&:content)
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Comment: You put me into the right track, I used a double "f.inputs, for:" because I wanted text_areas and only fields that belong to this particular page with each label.
Thank you again !